# Reading recently executed sql statements from WAL in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

How can I read the most recently executed sql statement? I think it's useful to analyze executed process. May I read it from wal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WAL logs changes to the memtable, not statements. And not all statements make changes, and thus WAL cannot be used, even if it would allow reconstructing changes *somehow*.
You can use `ysql-log-statement` https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/reference/configuration/yb-tserver/#ysql-log-statement to log some or all queries.

Or using audit logging https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/secure/audit-logging/.

There are additional features such as viewing `pg_stat_activity` to see [live running queries](https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/explore/query-1-performance/pg-stat-activity/), as well as using `pg_stat_statements` to view [slow-running queries](https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/explore/query-1-performance/pg-stat-statements/) that might help out. Neither gives you the exact last query but can help you narrow it down.